# truffle - should I create migrations files by myself?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

I am using `truffle`.

I run `truffle compile` and I get `json` files in `build/contracts` directory.

Now, truffle says I should run `truffle migrate` , but in the `migrations` folder, I only got `1_initial_migration.js` .

Should I make `migrations` files for each of my contracts by myself or does truffle's `1_initial_migration.js` still takes care of deploying all the dependency contracts too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to create a migrations file for each contract you want to deploy, you can simply deploy your contracts by configuring `1_initial_migration.js` as shown in the [docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations).

So, if you want to deploy `contracts\ExampleContract.sol` (and the Migrations contract,) the file should look at follows:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
const ExampleContract = artifacts.require("ExampleContract");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
   deployer.deploy(Migrations);
   deployer.deploy(ExampleContract);
};
```

And you don't have to add contracts to this file, which are imported in `ExampleContract`, if that answers second your question.

Comment: What's the reason of truffle compile then ? The reason I am asking this is because, now, I don't understand why interfaces are useful at all. I just wrote contract myContract is TestInterface {} and I didn't include any of the functions in myContract that testInterface has, but compile step still worked fine.

Comment: Well, when you *compile* your contracts, they are just compiled as an ABI (application binary interface) in those JSON files in the `build/contracts` folder. If you want to interact with them as you would do on the real Ethereum Mainnet, you have to *deploy* them using `truffle migrate`. For information about Solidity interfaces, see  [the docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.5/contracts.html#interfaces).

Comment: I think I asked something else in the comments about interfaces, but your first answer makes sense.